# node js express server postgres 500 internal server error

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

My api has stopped working, previously it worked fine and as far as i am aware I have changed nothing. When i tested my endpoint i received an internal server error.

Here is a link to my hosted api https://frozen-scrubland-34339.herokuapp.com/api

I have just checked some of my other apis and none are working either, same message. it appears my code isnt the issue but postgres itself?

Any help on what to do would be appreciated

When i tried to npm run prod to re-push it to heroku i received: 'Error: The server does not support SSL connections'
Again this was never an issue previously when it worked.

I imagine i have changed something with heroku itself by accident?

app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const apiRouter = require("./routers/api-router");
const cors = require("cors");
const {
  handle404s,
  handlePSQLErrors,
  handleCustomError,
} = require("./controllers/errorHandling");

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/api", apiRouter);

app.use("*", handle404s);
app.use(handlePSQLErrors);
app.use(handleCustomError);
module.exports = app;
```

connection.js

```
const { DB_URL } = process.env;
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

const baseConfig = {
  client: "pg",
  migrations: {
    directory: "./db/migrations",
  },
  seeds: {
    directory: "./db/seeds",
  },
};

const customConfigs = {
  development: { connection: { database: "away_days" } },
  test: { connection: { database: "away_days_test" } },
  production: {
    connection: {
      connectionString: DB_URL,
      ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
      },
    },
  },
};

module.exports = { ...baseConfig, ...customConfigs[ENV] };
```

Comment: I’m on mobile now. I’ll check when i at home. I think it’s about CORS. Can you check about that?

Comment: What's the message?

Comment: it just says 'internal server error'

Comment: I've called cors in my app.js. it was working fine. I left it a few weeks cam back and now it doesnt work.

Comment: `/api` seems fine it's the other endpoints which 500, please show relevant code for `/api/stadiums`, if you don't want to do that then you need to put better debugging in place, the code your showing is not useful